# sql query builder for select in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my application, I want to build sql query to get result set and export to excel. In my page I need to specify the criteria and the columns which are needed to show in excel.
I have gone through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S) post. In that we can select the required columns and can write where clause, and select from multiple tables, but it not support some functionalities for example 'Union',
Is there any way to build complex quires to get dynamic results from sql

Comment: Beware of dynamic sql. it's a security risk.

Comment: @ZoharPeled using a mix of checks against the information schema and parametrization the risk can be mitigated. If the application really does require SQL generation capability.

Comment: @NeilP You are correct, but let's now go with the assumption that everybody knows how to write a safe and well designed dynamic sql statement. in fact, most of the people that are tempted to use dynamic sql simply aren't aware of the fact that there is such a thing called [sql injection.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: was the answer useful?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend lightweight [SqlKata](https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder).

It allows to build dynamically SQL Query and execute it using any framework you wish (or built in Executor).

Supports:

- SqlServer, MySql, PostgreSql and Firebird providers
- Select, From, Where, Limit & Offset, Join, Group, Order, Having, Union/Except/Intersect, CRUD, String and Date operations, etc..

Sample with Union:

```
            var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
            var query = new Query("User")
                .Select("Id as UserId")
                .Select("Email")
                .Where("Id", "<", 10)
                .Union(new Query("User")
                    .Select("Id as UserId", "Email")
                    .Where("Id", ">", 15)
                    .Where("Id", "<", 20));

            var sqlResult = compiler.Compile(query);
```

It will generate the following sql query:

```
SELECT [Id] AS [UserId], [Email] FROM [User] WHERE [Id] < @p0 UNION (SELECT [Id] AS [UserId], [Email] FROM [User] WHERE [Id] > @p1 AND [Id] < @p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com), a sql query builder that support complex queries, union operator is not supported yet, but I am pretty sure that it will help you in your situation, it also saves u from sql injections since it uses parameter binding technique, check it out and hope it helps in solving ur problem

Comment: This project is very usefull!!

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a complex way to build your queries you have to type them:

```
Boolean doUnion = true;
String yourExternalCompsedWhere = "1=1";
String strQuery = String.Format(@"DECLARE @param int -- any type
--DECLARE anything else
SET @param = {0}
SELECT {1} ColumnA, {2} ColumnB FROM TableX WHERE Field3 = @param
WHERE {3}", param, "Field1", "Field2", yourExternalComposedWhere);
if (doUnion)
    strQuery += String.Format(@"
UNION
SELECT {0}, {1} FROM TableY WHERE Field7 != @param", "Field3", "Field4");

SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
sqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn);
SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlDR.Read())
{
//Do what you need to do
};
sqlDr.Close()
```

Following this schema you can add whatever you want; be aware that this way of acting is prone to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use entity's classes and lambdas take a look on LambdaSql.
For now it contains basic scenarios for `select` clause and `where` filters. Setting fields, where, group by, having, order by, joins, nested queries are already supported. Insert, Update and Delete are going to be supported later. It also contains some points to extend existing behavior. For example `Limit` is implemented using that way.

Example:

```
var qry = new SqlSelect
(
    new SqlSelect<Person>()
        .AddFields(p => p.Id, p => p.Name)
        .Where(SqlFilter<Person>.From(p => p.Name).EqualTo("Sergey"))
    , new SqlAlias("inner")
).AddFields<Person>(p => p.Name);

Console.WriteLine(qry.ParametricSql);
Console.WriteLine("---");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", qry.Parameters
    .Select(p => $"Name = {p.ParameterName}, Value = {p.Value}")));
```

Output:

```
SELECT
    inner.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        pe.Id, pe.Name
    FROM
        Person pe
    WHERE
        pe.Name = @w0
) AS inner
---
Name = @w0, Value = Sergey
```

See more here

https://github.com/Serg046/LambdaSql

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LambdaSql